# .htaccess file being overwritten by cPanel and breaking site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cpanel, whm

I'm the SysAdmin of an AWS EC2 instance hosting a public website. The instance is running CentOS 7 with WHM/cPanel. Our website uses both PHP 5.6 and 7.1, and cPanel utilizes EasyApache 4. Since the 26th of July, every two weeks at exactly 2:04AM our .htaccess file is being modified by cPanel and completely breaking our website. The website would no longer load the webpage but instead download a file simply called "download". The file was harmless and only contained some laravel markup.

Once we discovered that it was the .htaccess file causing the site issues, the simple fix of replacing the file with a version from a backup solved the issue temporarily. Last time it happened on the 8th, I tried to restrict access by setting to the .htaccess file by setting:

```
Set “Depth to recurse for .htaccess checks” to 0.
```

in cPanel, but no dice.

From some other posts/sites I've managed to figure out that it may be EasyApache doing the writing to the file, and that this happens when sites have multiple versions of PHP in use at the same time. Below is what's being added to the .htaccess file that's breaking it.

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php71” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Commenting this out immediately fixes the issue.

Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out a solution to this issue however and was hoping I could get some help here. The website as it is, is on ice development-wise and very few changes will be made in the future, and definitely none to the .htaccess file. There may be a quick, dirty fix changing the permissions of the .htaccess file to 444 but I want to figure out the actual issue as opposed to implementing that.

Comment: Did you figure out any sort of solution? I am having this problem as well.

Comment: Hey @AlmostPitt, I never did. I made a copy of the valid htacess file, then made a crontab to copy and overwrite the incorrect file as soon as it gets changed. Because it happened at 2:04:37AM every other Thursday, I set the cron to go at 2:05AM everyday, just incase. Its janky but it held up.

Comment: Interesting hack @HRDSysAdmin ! In my continued search, I found a solution, however, I haven't been able to try it yet. So, I cannot vouch for it's effectiveness yet. Here is the link: https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/prevent-easyapache-htaccess-file-modification/ (In case the link breaks in the future, here are the steps: 1) Login to WHM, 2) Navigate to "Server Configuration", 3) Go to "Tweak Settings", 4) Select the option "System", 5) Set "Depth" to recurse for .htaccess checks" to 0. 6) Click the button "Save".

Comment: Did you restart Apache after changing the "Depth to recurse.." to 0?